# How to Initialize Variable to Maximum Value

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to figure out how to initialize a variable in VBScript to its maximum value.

For example, in C++, I would do something like:

```
double x = MAX_DOUBLE;
```

I am not sure how to do this in VBScript.

***UPDATE***

For now, I have defined the variable myself as constant value in the global scope of the script. I am not sure if this is the most elegant way of doing this. Is there a built-in variable I can use?

```
Const MAX_DOUBLE = CDbl(1.79769313486232e307)
Const MIN_DOUBLE = CDbl(-1.79769313486232e307)
```

Comment: I don't think you can use a cast (`CDbl()`) when defining a constant. Are you not getting an error?

Comment: @Bond It doesn't give me an error. The reason I did the explicit cast was because I was getting an overflow when I didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never found the limits described on MSDN to be accurate for many of the VBScript data types. For example, the `Currency` type gives me an overflow for anything > `XXX.5625`, even though the docs say it should go to `XXX.5808`. Same thing for `Double`. The docs say the max should be `1.79769313486232e308` but that final `2` in the mantissa causes an overflow. These are the values I've used in the past:

```
Const MIN_BYTE     =  0
Const MAX_BYTE     =  255
Const MIN_INTEGER  = -32768
Const MAX_INTEGER  =  32767
Const MIN_LONG     = -2147483648
Const MAX_LONG     =  2147483647
Const MIN_SINGLE   = -3.402823e38
Const MAX_SINGLE   =  3.402823e38
Const MIN_DOUBLE   = -1.79769313486231e308
Const MAX_DOUBLE   =  1.79769313486231e308
Const MIN_CURRENCY = -922337203685477.5625
Const MAX_CURRENCY =  922337203685477.5625
Const MIN_DATE     = #100/1/1#
Const MAX_DATE     = #9999/12/31#
```

Because VBScript uses Variants, however, note that you may not get the type you expect when assigning a "max" (or min) value to a variable. For example:

```
b = MAX_BYTE      ' Actually type Integer
s = MAX_SINGLE    ' Actually type Double
c = MAX_CURRENCY  ' Actually type Double
```

If you want to ensure you're getting the proper data type in return, you'll need to explicitly cast:

```
b = CByte(MAX_BYTE)     ' Type Byte
s = CSng(MAX_SINGLE)    ' Type Single
c = CCur(MAX_CURRENCY)  ' Type Currency
```

Comment: Thanks for that list. I did encounter the Overflow when I used the value for MAX_DOUBLE and MIN_DOUBLE.

Comment: On my list or on MSDN's?

Comment: yes, the 308 is causing an overflow. I know that's the value I got from MSDN as well.